# U-sql error: Expected one of: AS EXCEPT FROM GROUP HAVING INTERSECT OPTION ORDER OUTER UNION UNION WHERE ';' ')' ','

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a following table:

```
EstimatedCurrentRevenue -- Revenue column value of yesterday
EstimatedPreviousRevenue  --- Revenue column value of current day
crmId
OwnerId
PercentageChange.
```

I am querying two snapshots of the similarly structured data in Azure data lake and trying to query the percentage change in Revenue.

Following is my query i am trying to join on OpportunityId to get the difference between the revenue values:

```
@opportunityRevenueData = SELECT (((opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue - optyPrevious.EstimatedPreviousRevenue)*100)/opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue) AS PercentageRevenueChange, optyPrevious.EstimatedPreviousRevenue, 
opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue, opty.crmId, opty.OwnerId From @opportunityCurrentData AS opty JOIN @opportunityPreviousData AS optyPrevious on opty.OpportunityId == optyPrevious.OpportunityId;
```

But i get the following error:

> E_CSC_USER_SYNTAXERROR: syntax error. Expected one of: AS EXCEPT FROM
>   GROUP HAVING INTERSECT OPTION ORDER OUTER UNION UNION WHERE ';' ')'
>   ','
>
> at token 'From', line 40
>
> near the ###:

This expression is having the problem i know but not sure how to fix it.
(((opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue - optyPrevious.EstimatedPreviousRevenue)*100)/opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue)

---

Please help, i am completely new to U-sql

Answer (score 2):

U-SQL is case-sensitive (as per [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/u-sql-identifiers)) with all SQL reserved words in UPPER CASE.  So you should capitalise the `FROM` and `ON` keywords in your statement, like this:

```
@opportunityRevenueData =
    SELECT (((opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue - optyPrevious.EstimatedPreviousRevenue) * 100) / opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue) AS PercentageRevenueChange,
           optyPrevious.EstimatedPreviousRevenue,
           opty.EstimatedCurrentRevenue,
           opty.crmId,
           opty.OwnerId
    FROM @opportunityCurrentData AS opty
         JOIN
             @opportunityPreviousData AS optyPrevious
         ON opty.OpportunityId == optyPrevious.OpportunityId;
```

Also, if you are completely new to U-SQL, you should consider working through some tutorials to establish the basics of the language, including case-sensitivity.  Start at http://usql.io/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my bad, it was a minor mistake in the whole script every keyword except this FROM was in smallcase.

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as answered and upvote if it has been useful for you.

Comment: Hi @AshutoshKumar, it looks like this is the answer - can you mark it as the answer please?

Comment: sorry, it says my answer is recorded but it doesn't change the public display, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This same crazy sounding error message can occur for (almost?) any USQL syntax error.  The answer above was clearly correct for the provided code.

However since many folks will probably get to this page from a search for 'AS EXCEPT FROM GROUP HAVING INTERSECT OPTION ORDER OUTER UNION UNION WHERE', I'd say the best advice to handle these is look closely at the snippet of your code that the error message has marked with '###'.

For example I got to this page upon getting a syntax error for a long query and it turned out I didn't have a casing issue, but just a malformed query with parens around the wrong thing.  Once I looked more closely at where in the snippet the ### symbol was, the error became clear.